# Catch22 Msft style: How do I remove a failed W7 SP1 update that doesn't show in installed updates-or available updates?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Leave it to Msft to make updates they recommend impossible to install. I installed the W7 SP1 update "successfully" but it doesn't show in the Windows edition info. It also doesn't show as a critical update anymore. 
So was it installed or wasn't it? Only Msft knows....
I'd like to uninstall it but of course this is a Msft product - so it doesn't show in the "installed updates" list. 
The event viewer shows there were issues with unrecognized usb drivers ... but I'm stuck until I can get my OS to *admit* it's not on SP1.

Comment: So you just recently installed SP1 it was deleted years ago.

Comment: Just restore the most recent full disk backup you've made before update?

Comment: run winver.exe and look if it shows Build 7600 (RTM) or 7601 (Sp1).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is a very common issue - in my case caused by Msft's install process being unable to detect 64bit machines. The solution was to find the 64bit update and force that to install over whatever Msft had tried to install. I didn't have to uninstall the failed update after all.